# Can I stop tenants from leaving their small, 1,500 electric oil-filled radiators ON while they are gone using an 'occupant sensor' control recepticle?

Tags: motion-sensor

I have two tenants who always forget to turn "OFF" their little 1,000 watt portable oil-filled radiator heaters when they leave for work all day! My electric bill is already too high, and I have been notified that the rates are going up across the board in Virginia by $85.00 per month in addition to what I am already paying which is currently $255.00. Is there an "OCCUPANCY MOTION SENSOR" receptacle that I can plug this type of heater into which can be set to completely shut off the heater after they have left the apt. for the day? They CANNOT seem to remember to turn off their heaters when they leave for work......Which they are [REQUIRED] to do in their SIGNED LEASE!
The electric bills are killing me as they do NOT HAVE separate electric meters! Their apartments are part of my main house!
Desperate Landlord in Lynchburg Virginia in need of HELP!

Comment: I'd look to figuring out **why** they need these heaters in the first place. If they use them often, and don't seem bothered by leaving them on during the day, that implies they don't have enough heat from the main heating system. What kind of heat do you supply to them? Do they have their own zone/thermostat?

Comment: Also keep in mind that any auto-off (motion based or time or whatever) will only work if they plug in the heater in the right receptacle. If they cheat by plugging it into a different receptacle, you lose. If they forget and plug their computer into the special receptacle and it turns off, they'll complain. And if things are so "permanent" that they really will always plug in the same heater in the same receptacle *all the time* then they probably should have a better heating system instead.

Comment: Does the property have any insulation? Looking at losses would be a first step.

Comment: Have you considered increasing their rent?

Comment: If leaving for work is the main problem, ie their absence is on a predictable schedule, I recommend a timer switch rather than an occupancy sensor.  Timers are more reliable, less fickle, and are equally easy to override.  A smart socket is an alternative that can be controlled by a schedule in its hub OR by occupancy or other sensors.

Comment: If they're breaking the terms of their lease, give them written notice of 90 days for the electric bill to come down or you'll evict them for breaking the lease. Of course, since you're on one meter, they've got a simple legal defense of "it's not our fault - he's the one using all the electricity" and there's no way for either of you to prove it's the other person's fault.

Comment: @FreeMan since running space heaters unattended **is against their UL-approved instructions** and creates a fire hazard, you can cut straight to "3-day notice to quit" - though if you're in a rent control area, I'd run it past a judge first.

Comment: Dear 613jay, I like your solution regarding a timer! The tenants live in 2 terrace 'flats' directly below a Historic 1886 Italianate Brick Townhouse. We always become friends with our tenants as we all live in close proximity. These 'flats' are protected from the cold and the elements by my 2nd & 3rd story living space above & the extremely thick brick walls inside and out! The rents are $600 + $75 utilities monthly! I rely on their 'cooperation' to keep the electric use down. The radiators [ARE] the provided heat! The flats are SMALL & cozy. I need a 7-day timer which will 'skip' Sat. & Sun.!

Comment: Harper, You are correct...and this IS IN MY LEASE! Unfortunately, solid tenants who pay their rent on time are an "asset" to a landlord. I would rather not cut to a "3-day notice to quit" over something like this. I would much rather find a way to accommodate the otherwise good tenant with a 'compromise' solution to overcome their inability to remember to turn off their portable oil-filled radiators when they leave for work for 8 hrs on week days! The [2] heaters which I provide do not get dangerously hot but do use a lot of electricity when needlessly left on when no one is at home.  Starr C.

Comment: Dear FreeMan, I can, according to the "LEASE" - add a 'surcharge' to their electric utility bill for excessive use on a month to month basis! However, this can cause some ill-will at times, so I would prefer a compromise of some kind like a pre-set "timer" which would work in tandem with the heater to address this problem. My tenants live directly below my Historic 1886 Italianate Brick Townhouse and we are on very friendly terms! I am sure they would cooperate with a [7-day timer] which turned the heaters off Mon.-Fri. 8AM-5PM then did NOT cut off on Saturday & Sunday if such a timer exists?

Comment: Dear manassehkatz, These apartments are small, cozy little 2-room 'flats' in an English basement on the terrace/garden level of my Historic 1886 Italianate-Victorian Townhouse. The original heating system was the single fireplace in each "flat". The fireplaces were sealed up years ago for safety reasons by the 2nd family who owned and occupied this 3-story brick home. I am the 3rd owner since 1886. The small quarters are beautiful & lovely, but never had their own independent heating systems. They are "CHARMING" & rent quickly @ $675 mo. I provide 2 small radiators for perfect heating in each!

Comment: Dear Solar Mike, The solid brick walls both inside and outside these two apartments are 3 or 4 bricks thick and are part of the "foundation" of my Historic 1886 Italianate Victorian Townhouse! Additionally, the entire back half of the 2-room apartments are actually under ground. Everything is well insulated right down to modern "storm windows", and it is always quite pleasant inside compared to the 'main house' above. It actually takes very little to heat the small space! The trouble is that the tenants always forget to turn OFF their heaters when leaving - causing the electric meter SPINNING!

Comment: Dear Aloysisus, One tenant has a 3-year LEASE with the Rent [$600] per month & the Utilities [$75] per month "locked in"! The other tenant still has 6 months left on his LEASE at the same reasonable rates. I have no overhead costs from these 2 rentals as they are simply 'space' on the Garden level of my Historic 1886 Italianate Victorian Townhouse which provide a little additional income for my wife & myself to HELP defray our expenses. With the coming increase in utility bills {which will soon TOTAL OVER $600 per mo}, I will be forced to increase [BOTH] my rent [&] utility charges TO BE SURE!

Comment: @Mr.StarrCavins you could have saved yourself a _lot_ of typing by [edit]ing your post to include all the info you just typed 6 times. Also, if you use the `@` symbol and start typing a user name (no space), you'll get a list of users & can click one. The `@` will actually cause the user to be notified that you've mentioned him so he can come look at what you've said. As it stands, addressing "Dear `<user>`" doesn't really help much and relies on the person randomly stopping back by to see that you're replying.

Comment: @FreeMan I have yet to be personally notified of any comment by anyone responding to me specifically. I am old school - born in 1947 - and used to the 'formal, polite' approach! Thank you for the 'tip'! Each comment was by a different individual, so I responded to them individually with different answers geared to each unique response to my initial question. I simply went down the list of people who I felt deserved a "reply". ACTUALLY.......You are the only one who took a moment to get back to me. I assume you still value the 'social graces' of polite communication - and for that I THANK YOU!

Answer (score 5):

### This is a legal mess

First, you really, really need to review landlord-tenant law. Because your strategy is penny-wise/pound-foolish.  You are presuming a right to do things that are totally illegal, like barge into their apartments to turn off heaters or stick plug-in gadgets on their heaters. Obviously your goal here is to save money.  **But if they report your violations to the law and tenants rights organizations, they'll treat you like a slumlord and it'll cost you tens of thousands of dollars**.

You're accustomed to doing things as you please, everyone cooperating, and the law protecting you. As soon as you become a landlord, you feel the backside of that - the laws protect *the tenants **from you***. You're the apocryphal bad guy now, and you have to walk the fine line.

I know you feel righteous.  But that is only one person's perspective.

### Metering or sub metering is the gold standard way to resolve this

In fact we did that with half our units, after a tenant set up a small business in their garage unit and seemed to spike the electric bill. (that side is wired in a way that lends itself to that).

I know you don't want to pay to have the electrician separate off circuits and outlets.  But that really is the best answer, and the only one that will transfer liability over to where it belongs.   The electrician will install two "sub-panels" and reroute circuits so that each tenant's lights and outlets come out of their sub-panel. Each subpanel will then be fed via one kind of meter or another.

Utility-side separate metering is the cleanest, but will cost more every month, and you can't control how much. That's because utilities charge sometimes unreasonable prices *per meter* regardless of usage. One town imposed a $60/month/meter fee. This sort of thing is going to be happening a lot, because power companies already are behind the curve on infrastructure maintenance, and emerging tech is changing the shape of the grid.  So the idea of creating more *utility* meters leaves a bad taste in my mouth.

Remember when you don't have a tenant, **you** pay those extra "metering" charges.

As such, **I prefer private sub-metering** *if you can pull it off legally* and there are complications there.  Remember, the system perceives you as an evil, exploiting landlord, and the burden of proof is on you to show otherwise.  So you want a sub-metering system that is as honest, fair  and straightforward as it can be. Ideally that involves third parties.

Any kind of metering system will involve establishing two new sub-panels, changing the panel end of circuits to come out of the subpanels, and possibly splitting a circuit or two.  It must be the case that tenant X's meter powers ONLY tenant X loads, and tenant Y's meter powers only tenant Y's loads.

It's OK if some tenant loads are still on your meter.  If those are hard-wired loads, you are probably pretty safe as few tenants will be willing to open up electrical boxes to steal power.  However, they certainly will get those 2-prong power adapters that screw into light bulb sockets, so I advise changing any lighting you still power to modern LED fixtures that do not have replaceable bulbs.

### Or just adjust the rent every month

This won't work in a rent-control area.  But outside of rent control, you can set the rent to anything you want, and the tenants just have to "lump it".  So you can simply change the rent every month, making a baseline of $1000 and adding on a portion of the electric bill.

How you divide the electric bill is very important, and goes into "game theory".

- For instance if you make each tenant pay 1/4 of the total electric (you paying half), then they will say "hey, if I waste electric I only pay 1/4 of the cost" which translates to them "practically free heat!"
- Or if you commit to cover the first $100 of the bill and the 2 tenants split the rest, then the two tenants are at each other's throats.  But they're also tense about *your* usage.
- Or make each tenant pay 50% of the electric, giving you a "free ride", giving you no incentive to save electricity.   Now the shoe is on the other foot! LOL!

See, none of these are pretty, nor is the status quo.  This is why sub-meters are better.

### SAFETY ALERT! Install *proper* electric heaters

Or, it's all fun and games until they burn your house down.

All plug-in "space heaters" are a safety disaster. The radiator type are *less unsafe* but still Really Not Good.  **The tenants should not be relying on plug-in space heaters**, that is sheer madness if you dislike ashes.

Nevermind all the other issues -- if I had a tenant running plug-in space heaters, I would install proper, safe, reliable Baseboard Heating, and I'd do it PDQ.  The stuff is CHEAP -- a 2000W unit from Cadet is fifty bucks.  Seriously.  I'd give them more built-in heating *than they know what to do with*, so they stop using space heaters forever.  Electricity cost-wise, it's exactly the same - Every KWH gives you exactly 3400 BTUs whether it's a plug-in or a baseboard.

Heck, I'd even sink the extra cost into relay control so that 24-volt thermostats can be used, and I'd run 18/5 thermostat wire, assuring a "C" wire.  That allows you (or them) to use the huge variety of programmable and smart thermostats on the market, such as the Nest if they want to control it from their phone from Timbuktu.  You and they could even share control that way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are motion sensor outlets and motion sensor adapters available.

But the best way is to have dedicated (separated) electric meters, e.g., via subboard or sub-panel.

Advantages:

- The tenant will exactly pay for what he uses, best practice/justice.
- No more  arguing (at least much less, only about common light, door bells, electric power for central heating control, pumps etc.) over the electric bill share. More peace and less distress for both parties.
- Incentive for the tenant to save energy. Educational benefit. Environmental benefit.
- Avoids bridging the  motion sensor outlets via extension cords.
- Better suited for the future's most probable heating systems based on heat pumps.
- With separated circuits inclusive separated circuit breakers/GFCIs, less mutual influence in case of trippings.

Disadvantages:

- Investment costs, if not done DIY. An electronic meter for 3 phases plus Neutral costs about 50€ (in Europe). Circuit breakers ca. 3€, GFCI ca. 35€.

Comment: Good idea. A bit complicated when apartments are carved out of a house. Plug generally in the US even if you can do your own electric work, you can't on rentals, and submetering is very highly regulated.

Comment: Making the rental portion a true rental unit by putting it on its own meter and allowing the tenants the privilege of paying their own way in life is probably the best way of doing it.  The costs will be quite a bit higher than noted in this answer, as the entire apartment will have to be rewired to a new panel and that panel will have to go to a new meter with a new power drop from the PoCo. If this is going to be a rental for the long term, though, it's the only logical way.

Comment: I used to own a flat, and have a separate meter for each unit, and one for public utilities. Tenants always pay their own utility bills.

Answer (score 1):

Passive infrared motion sensors probably won't work while the tenant is asleep.

If your tenants work and have fixed timetables, you could simply use a timer on the socket.

This has the advantage of turning the heating off some time before they leave, which saves power... and turning it on before they come back, so they will come back to a warm room.

Comment: Dear bobflux:  Your solution is perfect & cost effective! I have been renting these two Terrace Level Apartments for 36+ years and I have already spent a great deal on appliances, carpeting, upgrades, and remodeling...NOT to mention all new wiring, plumbing top line, large capacity hot water heaters etc. I also have a completely new electrical box which services both apartments & my personal residence! All I need is a 7-Day "timer" which I can program to set hours on Monday through Friday - Then leave Saturday & Sunday "open" with no automatic cut off hours. Does such a "TIMER" exist???

Comment: Thanks! Try googling "7 day timer plug"

Answer (score 0):

You can find a 'wifi smart plug' product that is rated for the power draw of your heater, and place that between the socket and the plug

These connect to a wifi network, and then there is an app, and you can link to google home, and configure to turn on when the tenant comes home (they can connect via their mobile phone). Also the basic setting is a timer, e.g., off at 8am, on at 5pm, which is configurable, so it will turn off automatically, and then if they are home, then it's just a push of a button on the phone to turn the heater on (including remotely), so it's not at all necessary to use proximity sensing.

Comment: The first one, at least, does not appear to be UL listed. Not recommended for installation in the US.

Comment: use which kind of thing ? there are two things there.

Comment: ...Any of that cheap crud.  It misses the point of the question because **it's more dangerous than the heaters!** I realize it never occurred to you to shill garbage, and shopping at eBay/Amazon is just what you normally do to solve such problems, but the lesson here is that mail order (including Amazon) bypasses our regulatory safety systems that protect consumers.  Never buy electrical gear mail order!

Comment: I live in Indonesia, so I don't use ebay or Amazon, and there aren't any regulatory safety systems here. I am sure you can find a similar product from a different source. The focus is not on the specific product at all.

Comment: @thelawnet, then consider editing your answer to recommend "some sort of home automation plug that can be controlled digitally and meets your country's regulations". By including a picture of a specific item, you're directing (unintentionally or not) people's attention to the specific thing shown.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for contributing and good edit. As far as "there aren't any codes or regulatory rules here" *everybody keeps saying that*... literally I should put a sticker on my car for every locality.  They'd think I was a world traveler LOL.  Texas, outstate Oregon, Saipan (it's the USA and is on NEC 2008), the Philippines,  I even have people inside the EU claim it!  It's rarely ever true, they just haven't had personal experience with enforcement actions, which are often post-incident.

Comment: I didn't say there are no codes or regulatory rules in theory , it's more that they don't serve to protect the consumer at all in practice - in that my local hardware store sells 0.5mm^2 cable marked as 1.5mm^2, so I'd have to shop online to get something that *isn't* dangerous. The product I posted earlier but have removed  is sold here via a local importer, and it has a licence marked on the box, which is a 'radio licence', from the relevant ministry. That's nothing to do with the electrical safety of course. For whatever reason there are rules on imported cosmetics, but not on electronics.

Answer (score 0):

I like @bobflux idea using the infrared sensor. We use them in public restrooms where the occupants are motionless (like the sleeping tenant). Motion detectors rely on the tenant moving enough to activate the device. Infrared sensor works fine, except maybe when the tenant goes to the grocery store for an hour.